# My SVG button is not changing colors when i hover over it

Tags: html, css, svg, button, hover

I have a button that has an SVG inside it, in my CSS the icon changes color when you hover over it, the same thing with the SVG. But I have to put my mouse directly on the SVG to fill the color, I'm new to SVGs, so if anyone can help I put a screenshot and the code I used. [image]

```css
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 47px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(172, 170, 170, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
  height: 41px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-left: none;
}

.icon:hover {
  background-color: #5b9e4d;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(172, 170, 170, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
}

.icon:active {
  background-color: #5b9e4d;
  outline: none;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: white;
}

svg {
  fill: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: center;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 33px;
  min-width: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="icon searchIcon">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen? Sowe can recreate your issue and solve it.

Comment: ill get to it, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Heres the JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7yvkswqj/) @BeulahAkindele

Comment: The hover effect works on the jsfiddle.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele the problem is, i want the svg to change to white when i hover over any part of the button. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh I see, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are hovering over the parent but want to change the child's property. So you would set the hover effect to the parent, then write the changes to the child.

Like this:

```css
.icon:hover svg{
  fill: white;
}
```

```css
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 47px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(172, 170, 170, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
  height: 41px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-left: none;
}

.icon:hover {
  background-color: #5b9e4d;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(172, 170, 170, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
}

.icon:active {
  background-color: #5b9e4d;
  outline: none;
}

.icon:hover svg {
  fill: white;
}

svg {
  fill: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: center;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 33px;
  min-width: 2px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="icon searchIcon">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: No biggy, you can use any type of selector for the parent and child. And you can't set hover on the child and affect the parent (you can with CSS hack and js but out of the box you can't).